# How do i add an attachment to an email?

Tags: php, javascript, html, attachment

This may seem like an easy question, but --

How do i make it so when a user clicks on a link on my site, it opens up an outlook (or whatever client they use) with the file (in the link) as an attachment?

I don't want to use php's `mail()` function since i want the user to be able to send it as an attachment him or herself.

Or is this whole thing impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: the closest is using <a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">Send email</a>, but they will have to add an attachment themselves, and it will have to be on their machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. At most you can set the `To:` and `Subject:` lines via the link itself, but you can't force an attachment.

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?subject='Send me lots of spam'">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: `&body='Here is what the email says'` is commonly accepted too, but not universally. As you say, attachments are right out.

Comment: Makes me wonder what would happen if you did `body=mime_headers+base64_data_here`. most likely insert it verbatim (phew).

Comment: kk, thanks, i came up with a php/ajax solution instead of using mailto

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't do this. The best you could do is [mailto](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html) link which unfortunately doesn't allow to set attachments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form field for the user to enter his / her e-mail, then post to a php file which will grab that e-mail addr and send your attachment.

besides - mailto links are a pain in the A$$ for some users because they may be using a web based e-mail client as their primary, and a mailto will force something like outlook to open